# How to do a SQLiteDatabase contains search in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

As far as I'm aware of the character `?` is used as a placeholder and it will be replaced with the value that you pass in the `whereArgs` `String` array.

This is my code for the query:

```
String whereClause = null;
String[] whereArgs = null;
if (search != "") {
    whereClause = InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_ITEM_NAME +
            " CONTAINS(" + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_ITEM_NAME + ",?)";
    whereArgs = new String[]{search};
}

Cursor cursor = db.query(InventoryEntry.TABLE_NAME,
        null,
        whereClause,
        whereArgs,
        null,
        null,
        orderBy
);
```

When I go to execute the query I get the following error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CONTAINS": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemName CONTAINS(itemName,?) ORDER BY date ASC
```

What do I need to change so that my query will be in the form of:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemName CONTAINS(itemName,`search`);
```

Also, is it proper practice to use `CONTAINS` over `LIKE`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not have a `CONTAINS` keyword.

You could do something `LIKE` this:

```
whereClause = InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_ITEM_NAME +
        " LIKE " + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_ITEM_NAME +
        " OR " + InventoryEntry.COLUMN_INVENTORY_ITEM_NAME +
        " LIKE ?";
whereArgs = new String[]{search};
```

Also, do not compare strings with the `!=` operator, use the `equals()` method::

```
if (!"".equals(search)) {
    // ...
}
```

Or check the length of the `String`:

```
if (search != null && search.length() > 0) {
    // ...
}
```

The `!=` operator checks for reference equality when comparing objects.